# Add new counter (trap_id) field which increments by 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, snmp

**Code:**

```
filter {
    if ([trap_id]) {
        mutate {
               update => { "trap_id" => "trap_id"++ }
               }
    else
        mutate {
               add_field => { "trap_id" => 1 }
               }
                   }
}
```

**Scenario**:
I'm trying to introduce a new field(trap_id) which needs to increment by 1 every time a trap is generated.

**Error:**
:ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 26, column 50 (byte 1229) after filter {\n

which points to line : update => { "trap_id" => "trap_id"++ }

**Question:**
How do I fix the error? or Is this the right way to do for the given scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot increment a field using that syntax. You might be able to use the [math](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-math) filter (although you would need to install it, and it has not been updated for three years), or you could do it in ruby.

```
ruby {
    init => '@trap_id = 0'
    code => '
        @trap_id += 1
        event.set("trap_id", @trap_id)
    '
}
```

You will need to set pipeline.workers to 1 for this to work reliably. If there are multiple pipeline worker threads then access to the instance variable will not be synchronised across them. It may work almost all of the time but it is not impossible for two threads to increment @trap_id before either of them calls event.set. If for some reason the call to event.set actually has to reference memory again (as opposed to a register) then this will get the wrong result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it worked!  I'm new to logstash, why should the "pipelines.workers" field be set to 1?

Comment: Updated to expand on that.

Comment: noticed that, every time I restart the logstash service the 'trap_id' is being reset to 1. how do I overcome this? (i.e counter starts from the number it left off)

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. You would need to persist the trap_id value externally (e.g. in elasticsearch, or in a file on disk) and recover it. You would need to persist the value every time it is incremented, which greatly increases the cost of the filter.